# Как одновременно переименовывать в vs code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Где то видел переименование в режиме реального времени, то есть объявил несколько переменных и захотел их переименовать и зажимая определенную комбинацию клавиш переименовываешь одну переменную сразу во всем местах где она есть в коде. С помощью какой комбинации клавиш или какого плагина можно так же сделать в vs code? 
p.s. клавиша f2 не то

Comment: Правой кнопкой на переменную - `Рефакторинг > Переименовать`. А так в основном, ставим курсор на переменную и жмем на `F2`. Вроде, больше нет никакой возможности.

Comment: Я добавил расширение - sublime text keymap. И все команды как в sublime. CMD + D (ctrl + D в винде) - мультивыделенеие. В разных файлах - просто поиск + замена

Comment: @exvayn, `ctrl`+D и так работало

Comment: @Grundy пиар, через stackoverflow:D

Answer (score 4):

cmd+f2 на mac и ctrl+f2 на windows. сам задал вопрос, сам ответил:D

Comment: у меня на маке это сочетание не работает

Answer (score 0):

Также есть возможность выборочного выделения левой кнопкой мыши, зажимая Alt. Вдруг кому и этот вариант пригодится)